# Lxml import issues when using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, anaconda, lxml

I am trying to use Scrapy with Anaconda/Miniconda on Windows 10. Installation goes fine, but trying to actually run Scrapy gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried reinstalling Scrapy, lxml, and Anaconda itself (this time, I'm using a clean install of Miniconda), as well as downloading unofficial lxml build from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, as suggested in one of the answers on Stack Overflow, but the problem persists. I have also done this on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance started from scratch, but I'm getting the same issue.

It seems to be something relatively common, but I couldn't find an answer that would work for me. What's an appropriate way to address this? Is it just about lxml, or is there something else causing this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me on current Miniconda3.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes

Comment: No, I used pip to install packages from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Usually it's not a good idea to mix pip and conda packages.

Comment: Thanks! So you're suggesting to do a clean install of Miniconda, and then to install scrapy and other packages from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, right?